# Stop click propagation on a custom div within a leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have a custom div (with settings) within a map. I would like click event not to propagate to map when a user clicks on the div. How could one achieve such behavior?

Leaflet version 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for [`L.DomEvent.stopPropagation()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#domevent-stoppropagation).

Comment: And `L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(myDiv)` if you want to disable all click-related events for a div.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else coming here from a search engine, if you are trying to prevent clicks from a circle or other interactive layer from being handled by the underlying object (other circle or the map itself) you could also create the layer passing the option `bubblingMouseEvents: false`

Documentation: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#interactive-layer